# How to run javascript unit tests against different dependency versions?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dependencies, jestjs

In Python, I can do this by using [Tox](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) and [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/).
They enable me to run my unit tests in different combinations of Python versions and dependencies.

In example, for some reason, i need to test this function to run against `currency.js@~1.1.0` and `currency.js@~1.2.0`.

```js
import * as currency from 'currency.js';

export function getAmount(amountStr: string): number {
  return currency(amountStr).intValue;
}
```

```js
import { getAmount } from './get-amount';

describe('getAmount', () => {
  [
    { given: 'A$ 1.00', expecting: 100 },
    { given: 'A$ 1.33', expecting: 133 },
    { given: 'A$ 1.89', expecting: 189 },
  ].forEach(({ given, expecting }) => {
    describe(`given ${given}`, () => {
      it(`should return ${expecting}`, () => {
        expect(getAmount(given)).toEqual(expecting);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

So it's like I am asking:  What is the NodeJS equivalent of Python Tox?

For more context, i am using TypeScript, Angular and [jest](https://jestjs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

NPM allows you to alias libraries when you install them:

`npm install currency.js-legacy@npm:currency.js@1.1.0`

So you can install multiple versions of a library in question and make them available under different names.

Then import both in your test files and use whichever you need. Eg:

```
import currency from 'currency.js';
import currency-legacy from `currency.js-legacy';
```

I haven't tested the code but you can get the idea from the above anyway.